# 'Swap' values within a range

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

I get data that is a floating point value between `1` and `7`. 
`1` is bad, `7` is good.

Sometimes, when I get that data, I'd like to 'reverse' it, as the questions were written negatively, where `1` is good, and `7` bad.

---

A score of `1` should be 'swapped' to a score of `7`.

A score of `2` should be 'swapped' to a score of `6`.

A score of `2.5` should be 'swapped' to a score of `4.5`.

---

Originally I thought I could use an array:

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
return array[answer] - 1;
```

or `Math.abs(answer - 6)` but neither are going to work out.

Comment: Don't you mean that 2.5 should be mapped to 5.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need an array, if your values are fixed (from 1 to 7) you can just substract from 8:

`return 8 - answer;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function to achieve that:

```
function reverseRating(rating) {
   return 8 - rating
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function accomplishes this:

```
function reverseOnScale(answer, from, to) {
  answerMinus = answer - from;
  reversedMinus = Math.abs(answerMinus - (to - from));
  reversed = reversedMinus + from;
  return reversed;
}
```

Usage example:

```
reverseOnScale(5, 1, 7);
```

Outputs the value 3.

Comment: @A.Llorente You're right, I edited it to Javascript code.